# Admin Console and Jboss Web Services Console

Tags: web, service, jboss

am using Jboss 6, my problem is that when I want to view my admin console it will give me this>>>

```
HTTP Status 404 - /admin-console/
type Status report
message /admin-console/
description The requested resource (/admin-console/) is not available.
JBoss Web/3.0.0-CR2
```

and  it goes the same if I want to view my Jboss Web Services Console,>>

```
HTTP Status 404 - /jbossws/
type Status report
message /jbossws/
description The requested resource (/jbossws/) is not available.
JBoss Web/3.0.0-CR2
```

what is the problem actually? is there anything to do with admin console.war?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have corrupted the JBoss installation, highly reccomended to use a fresh installation and deploy your application rather than debug this.